# Conditional Probability- Linked Experiments

Tags: probability

There are two fair coins (i.e. Heads and Tails are equally likely for tosses for both). Coin 1 is tossed $3$ times. Let $X$ be the number of heads that occur. After this, Coin 2 is tossed $X$ times. Let $Y$ be the number of Heads we obtain with Coin 2. The Probability $\Pr(X \geq 2 \mid Y=1)$ equals?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

In general:$$P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$$

Comment: I used the following approach:
Given Y=1, means that Coin 2 has obtained Only one head. 
Given X ≥2 means that either X=2 Or X=3 
So the question reduces to Pr(X=2|Y=1) + Pr(X=3|Y=1) 
But still I was unable to retrieve the correct ans

Comment: @ManasManoj  Please edit your question to show us your calculations.  That will make it easier to determine where you made a mistake.  Did you remember to divide by $\Pr(Y = 1)$?

Comment: That is a good start. Now apply the hint I gave you on both terms.